# Overriding and extending classes in CodIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to override the CodeIgniter form validation library and extend it. When I place my overridden class in `application/core` CodeIgniter loads the core one instead. However if I put it in `application/libraries` it loads the overridden class but when I put `MY_Form_validation.php` in with it CodeIgniter loads the core form validation library instead of the overridden one. So how can I override and extend the overridden core library.

Comment: You can ref this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your question. Let me know if this is what you ask: When you override OTHER library (putting a MY_'library_name' in application/libraries) than MY_Form_validation.php, it works, but not with MY_Form_validation.php?

Answer (score 0):

Here your extending library file should be at in **`application/libraries/`** directory. See more http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Follow this steps when extend library not loading

1. The class declaration must extend the parent class. Check did you extend the correct class.
2. Check prefix your class name & file name prefix is correct all as defined in config file. Are case sensitive remember this.
3. Check your file is in correct location better your file is in **`application/libraries/`** directory.
4. Check you are correctly loading your library.

I hope this help you.